# Copy the contents of a Parent class object to child class object in scala

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have 2 classes.

```
  Class A {
      var something : String =_
   }
   Class B extends A{
      var somethingElse : String =_
   }
```

I will instantiate these 2 classes separately.

```
var a = new A 

a.something ="test me"

var b = new B
```

before start assigning values to `b` I want to copy content of object `a` into `b` . Is it possible to do this in scala using reflection or any third party API?

Comment: interesting, why do you prefer `var something: String = _` instead of `class A(something: String)`

Comment: I will use reflection to create class A from a key value pair and gain using another reflection to create Class b which is everything from A and some extra fields.